# scope of commerce facade in hybris

Tags: spring, sap-commerce-cloud

why is the scope of commerce facades marked prototype by default ? Is it that we always need a new instance of the requested facade every time we refer it or am I missing something here while understanding the concept of commerce facades in hybris ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In *commercefacades-spring.xml* only some populators and some POJOs are marked prototype.

The facades are still singletons since they are noting but special services.

Answer (score 0):

Hybris v5.x
Facades are singleton scoped beans by default. There is no need to create a new instance of facade object on every request.
Facades in Hybris are the implementation of Facade Design Pattern. To understand them deeply follow the links:
https://wiki.hybris.com/display/release5/Using+Facades+and+DTOs+-+Best+Practice 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern